# Multi-threaded code and condition variable usage

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, monitor, condition-variable

A multi-threaded piece of code accesses a resource (eg: a filesystem) asynchronously.

To achieve this, I'll use condition variables. Suppose the `FileSystem` is an interface like:

```
class FileSystem {
    // sends a read request to the fileSystem
    read(String fileName) {
        // ...
        // upon completion, execute a callback
        callback(returnCode, buffer);
    }
}
```

I have now an application accessing the `FileSystem`. Suppose I can issue multiple reads through a `readFile()` method.
The operation should write data to the byte buffer passed to it.

```
// constructor
public Test() {
    FileSystem disk = ...
    boolean readReady = ...
    Lock lock = ...

    Condition responseReady = lock.newCondition();
}

// the read file method in quesiton
public void readFile(String file) {
    try {
        lock.lock(); // lets imagine this operation needs a lock

        // this operation may take a while to complete; 
        // but the method should return immediately
        disk.read(file); 

        while (!readReady) { // <<< THIS
            responseReady.awaitUninterruptibly();
        }
    } 
    finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public void callback(int returnCode, byte[] buffer) {
    // other code snipped...

    readReady = true;  // <<< AND THIS
    responseReady.signal();
}
```

Is this the correct way to use condition variables? Will `readFile()` return immediately?

(I know there is some sillyness in using locks for reads, but writing to a file is also an option.)

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot missing from your question (i.e. no specific mention of Threads) but I will try to answer anyway.

Neither the lock nor the conditional variables give you background capabilities -- they just are used for a thread to wait for signals from other threads.  Although you don't mention it, the `disk.read(file)` method could spawn a thread to do the IO and then return immediately but the caller is going to sit in the `readReady` loop anyway which seems pointless.  If the caller has to wait then it could perform the IO itself.

A better pattern could be to use something like the Java 5 Executors service:

```
 ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int numThreads);
```

You can then call `pool.submit(Callable)` which will submit the job to be performed in the background in another thread (when the pool next has one available).  Submit returns a `Future` which the caller can use to investigate if the background task has finished.  It can return a result object as well.  The concurrent classes take care of the locking and conditional signal/wait logic for you.

Hope this helps.

p.s. Also, you should make `readReady` be volatile since it is not synchronized.